# Form from another model in a view

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

So I'm trying to extend the Blog tutorial adding some comments:

```
Post hasMany Comments
```

I want to display the add comment form in the same view as the 'post view'. Thing is I don't know the best way to get this approach. I thought about three ways:

- Creating a function in Comments Controller to handle the data.
- Creating a function in Post Controller to handle the data.
- Deal with the data in the same function that deals with the post views.

The main problem with the two first 'solutions' is that the validation errors doesn't show up in the form unless I do some messy hacking of saving the invalidated field in a session variable and then parsing the variable on the beforeFilter callback, like this:

```
function beforeFilter () {
    if ($this->Session->check('comment_error')) {
        $this->Post->Comment->validationErrors = $this->Session->read('comment_error');
        $this->Session->delete('comment_error');
    }
}
```

What I basically do is adapt the invalidated fields to the actual view and allow it to show properly. This works really well, but it seems so ugly to me. What would be the best approach?

Another related question: should a controller reflect a view? I mean on that example, I thought about only having a Comment Model and dealing with all the data in the controller where's the form to add a comment (even though it's in the Post Controller).

Comment: Keep your Comment logic in your Comments controller, not Post controller.  Reason: what if tomorrow, you decide you want to add those comments to 'profiles', or 'images'...etc.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But what about the validation errors? Do you think my solution is ok or is there a better one to show them correctly wherever the form is?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better solution than that - just don't have time to check atm :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the Mutlivalidatable behaviour: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model

This allows you to define more than 1 validation ruleset per model. Use your controller to determine which one to apply upon posting something.

P.S. I have only ever used this on a Cake 1.3 project, not sure if it'll work on 2.0.

Comment: That's actually really interesting, but not a great solution because it would require me to declare de validation rules in the Post Model, instead of the Comment Model. But thanks for sharing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I see it this way:

1. Under every post there is an input box "Add comment" with a button to submit.
2. After submitting some text a form redirects to comments_controller where the comment is saved with this post_id, body, author, date etc.
3. After the comment is saved and all the logic is done it takes you back to the post.
4. Under each post there are all related comments displayed (having the same post_id sorted by date or whatever).

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. But the main issue is that Cake doesn't keep the validationError array after a redirect. I've been looking deep into the Google Groups archive and found out that everyone ends up solving the issue the more-or-less the same way I did (storing in a Session variable). I wonder if the Cake developers are aware of this stupid limitation...